# How to update data on a react app from python?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I have this basic app that generates a form form a Json file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const schema = {
  "title": "A registration form",
  "description": "A simple form example.",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name",
      "default": ""
    },
    "telephone": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Telephone",
      "minLength": 10
    }
  }
}

const log = type => console.log.bind(console, type);

render(
  <Form
    schema={schema}
    autocomplete="on"
    onChange={log("changed")}
    onSubmit={log("submitted")}
    onError={log("errors")}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image]

Now, what I need is to be able to change the form at will by changing the Json file/content:

```
const schema = {
  "title": "A registration form",
  "description": "A simple form example.",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name",
      "default": ""
    },
    "telephone": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Telephone",
      "minLength": 10
    }
  }
}
```

I have that information from another app on Python and what I was thinking was to make Post request to react to send this information. But now I'm seeing that react is only a front end framework, so I'm not sure if is possible to receive request there or if is only able to make request, which will be a big change in the architecture I was thinking of

Answer (score 0):

You could use React to send a GET request to a Python server to get the data you need using any client-side fetching method and render the result based on such data. This requires a Python  server to host an endpoint to use.